# Migrate from SBJson 2.2 to SBJson 5

Tags: sbjson

Hello We are using SBJson lib with version   pod 'SBJson', '~>2.2.3' and want migrate to latest version pod 'SBJson5', '~> 5.0.0'.

What will be effort to migrate. I  mean will it support old methods or do i need find the deprecated or changed methods or any other specific change.

Does any one used this lib or done migration with SBJson do post to this thread.
Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how complicated your usage is, but you will definitively have to do some manual edits. I released version 3, with a major shift in focus towards streaming JSON way back in 2011, and I'm frankly amazed version 2.x.x even compiles today!

I tried to document the changes in the repo's [NEWS](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/master/NEWS.md) file. When naming the releases I tried to follow [SemVer](http://semver.org), which means that every 2.x.x -> 3.x.x and 3.x.x -> 4.x.x and 4.x.x -> 5.x.x were named thus because they all broke backwards compatibility in some way.

For version 3 the API went through a big change to focus on streaming. Much of the API changed to support this. Version 4 further removed old methods that had been obsoleted in the 3.1.x, 3.2.x and 3.3.x series. For 4 -> 5 the breaking change was very small: the API stayed the same, and only the behaviour is slightly different. ("Naked Scalars", e.g. strings and numbers not wrapped it an array or object, is now accepted as per the updated JSON RFC.)

Have you considered whether you actually need to use SBJson? You may be better off just using NSJSONSerialisation. After all it's been in the iOS SDK since iOS 5, and in the Mac SDK since a bit after that. The main benefit of using SBJson is if you want to be able to start parsing JSON before it's fully downloaded. (Thus improving *perceived* latency.)

Other issues you may run into: I fixed *a lot* of bugs since 2.x.x releases, which means the parser is much stricter now than it was back then. (Due to bugs it used to allow all sorts of broken JSON, and broken UTF-8.) So if you rely on any of that behaviour you will be out of luck. Hopefully that's not the case :-)